# Unity+Firebase-Database[Error] WebSocket: ws_0 - could not connect

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I cant seem to figure out a working solution to this error, more complete:

> 018-06-01 10:33:09 PM [Error] **WebSocket: ws_0 - could not connect**
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): **No route to host**
>
> 2018-06-01 10:33:09 PM [Error] WebSocket: ws_0 - **WebSocketException during handshake**
>   Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.WebSocketException: unknown host: ########.firebaseio.com ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host

**Take note**, the above errors repeat a few times every second, with ws_# incrementing by one each time

Unity 2018.1.1f1

Firebase-Database: Whatever is newest, got a few days ago

Bit of code:

```
void Start() {
    FirebaseApp.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose;
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose; // Or your database instance, if not using the default.

    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
            FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
            // NOTE: You'll need to replace this url with your Firebase App's database
            // path in order for the database connection to work correctly in editor.
            app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://########.firebaseio.com/");
            if (app.Options.DatabaseUrl != null) app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(app.Options.DatabaseUrl);
        } else {
            Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my attempt to access the firebase database

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
staticLocalData.thisUser = new UserData();
staticLocalData.thisUser.userID = newUser.UserId;
staticLocalData.thisUser.email = email;
staticLocalData.thisUser.firstName = firstName;
staticLocalData.thisUser.lastName = lastName;
registerData temp = new registerData();
temp.firstName = firstName;
temp.lastName = lastName;
temp.email = email;
temp.userName = userName;

Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(temp));
mDatabaseRef.Child("users").SetValueAsync("saddsa:23");  
//mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(newUser.UserId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(JsonUtility.ToJson(temp));
```

Ruleset: (Should allow for all)

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Additional notes:

- Firebase authentication is used and works perfectly, i just cant operate/access the database
- Been  using this as my main reference: 
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data
- using net 3x AND 4x, same result
- also Mono

Comment: Your code is for the Firebase Realtime Database, but the security rules you show are for Cloud Firestore. The two databases are completely separate, so make sure the security rules and database match.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, i posted the wrong one, i updated it with the firebase side

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That being said i did initially make the project as firestore, but i can switch between firestore and firebase in the project page. Would this have any impact on the situation?

Comment: The message "No route to host" seems to indicate that the client can't reach the Firebase servers. This may indicate a problem in the client itself (e.g. a proxy) or a problem between the client and server (e.g. a firewall).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen where would i want to look to debug this? Keep in mind the authentication part of firebase works perfectly. Also, once i exit the Unity editor play mode, there errors continue to pop up. and only stop when i hit play in the editor again

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Upon further testing, this line is what causes the errors to start appearing: DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

Comment: If Auth works and RTDB doesn't, it might be a firewall blocking (web) socket traffic. But that's nothing more than an (slightly educated) guess. A good way to test that theory would to try from another network, e.g. at home, or on your phone's data plan.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think your educated is correct. I have the same problem. I have turned the firewall off and it works about 50% of the time other times it produces the same problem. It seems like no one has a fix for this issue...

Answer (score 8):

Using:

Unity Editor 2018.2.5f1 on OSX Sierra 10.12.6

scripting Runtime 4.x

scripting backend IL2CPP

API Level 4.x

Firebase plugin version 5.2.1

This exact same problem was happening. This seemed to be related to the Mono Websocket implementations, as discussed in more detail on the following issues:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/106

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/162

The Firebase dev team went around what is described there by providing their own native websocket implementations for each platform. Apparently the Unity Editor implementation is lagging behind.

The way to workaround this issue here was by disabling the FirebaseDatabase.dll under ../Firebase/Plugins/Mono/ for the editor platform, and then enabling the one FirebaseDatabase.dll directly under ../Firebase/Plugins/ instead.

So far, so good.

Comment: What do you mean by "disabling" a dll? I've been renaming / deleting them with no success

Comment: When you click on the dll file that is mentioned above, you will see checkboxes of disable and enable. But disabling the dll uder mono is affecting the database calls of my project

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed in new firebase_sdk_v6.2.1 July release