# how to fix ' EntryPointNotFoundException: SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_DatabaseInternal' error in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to connect the firebase with unity, I use this example 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity
and when I run the program it gives me an error as in the picture below.
I couldn't find any solution, can someone help me?
Note: I tried this example with the same steps on another computer and it works correctly[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w04rY.png)

Answer (score 0):

please see this thread may help you

[Unable To Write Data to Firebase Database via Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559803/unable-to-write-data-to-firebase-database-via-unity?noredirect=1#comment92062341_52559803)

Firebase.Database . You may found 3 Firebase.Database in unity Inspector.

Found the Firebase.database in plugins/ios.

enable the Editor support and ios

and save it. and deselect the editor support and ios in another 2 firebase.database.

and save it.

your error will be solved.

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue, it may be because the file in Asset/firebase/plugins/mono is not enabled in editor - make sure it is (and make sure ONLY this firebase.database file is enabled in editor)

- this works for the editor - dont know about building to ios/android.