# Errors when accessing Firebase Realtime Database in Unity: could not connect, Unknown host

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database to store stats in my game. I referred to their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data) and wrote the following code. (I didn't want to overcomplicate anything before testing.)

```
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;

public class DatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    private void Start()
    {
       FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://#####.firebaseio.com/");
       reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }
}
```

Next, I attached the script to the Main Camera in an empty scene and clicked Play to test it. But I got endless errors like these:

> WebSocket: ws_0 - could not connect System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
> (0x80004005): No route to host
>
> WebSocket: ws_0 - WebSocketException during handshake
> Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.WebSocketException: unknown host:
>
> .firebaseio.com  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host

I found others' workarounds online including switching to .NET 3.5, using Firebase SDK v5.4.4 instead, and [disabling Firebase/Plugins/Mono/FirebaseDatabase.dll then enabling the one under Firebase/Plugins/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651865/unityfirebase-databaseerror-websocket-ws-0-could-not-connect). But none of them seemed to work for me. I need .NET 4.0 since 3.5 will soon be removed, and I couldn't find an older version of this SDK (even [the magical link](https://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/unity/firebase_unity_sdk_$%7Bversion%7D.zip) is invalid).

**Additional Notes:**

- I've changed the **rules** of my database, both write and read set to true
- I'm building for iOS and Android platforms
- Operating System: Mac OS 10.14.3
- Unity Engine version: 2018.3.8f1
- Firebase SDK version: 5.5.0
- Scripting Backend: Mono

Comment: just for covering the rest: You configured the [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules) for public access as mentioned in your link? And .. you can generally ping that Url?

Comment: @derHugo Yes. I can access the URL through my browser and other apps.